# How Can I physically see running Cronjobs?

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have cronjobs that execute PHP files at pre-determined times. These scrips can take over an hour to complete. I want to be able to physically monitor the scripts. I have logs, of course, and lots of ways to handle errors, but sometimes I just like to see what's happening.

Previously I did this on Windows where I would schedule a task which would launch in a shell that would remain open while the task ran.

Can I do this on Linux? Using SSH? Something perhaps like using `screen` with the cron? I'm using the AWS version of Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: [man ps](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)

Comment: You can ssh into your server and use ps to check for running processes. You can also use TOP to see what is still running.

Comment: you can use `ps -A | grep "yourscript.extension"`

Comment: @Alex - Will that show the actual scripts running? Not just show me the processes?  In the same way as if I had run the php script directly from the shell?

Comment: Do you want to monitor the output of the script? You said, you were logging ...

Comment: Yes, I want to monitor the output. Sorry, if I was not more clear.

Comment: @user2029890 it will show you if the script is running or not.

Comment: @user2029890 if you want to monitor data you can just throw them into logs in crontab like `cron yourscript.php >> /var/log/reports.log` than you can `tailf /var/log/reports.log` to see if data is being write in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe output of a cronjob to a logfile, and you can use unix tools (tail, watch, etc) to view all the output as it goes, e.g. the following redirects STDERR as well as STDOUT to a log file:-

```
/usr/bin/really_long_script.sh > /tmp/script.log 2>&1

tail -f /tmp/script.log
```

Comment: All the answers were the same idea. I accepted this one because of hte examples

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (though sligtly dirty) way to do this, is to set an environment variable in crontab:

```
* * * * * THIS_IS_A_CRON=1 /path/to/script
```

Then, to see if they're running on your machine:

```
ps auxe | grep THIS_IS_A_CRON
```

That'll list all proces (if any) that were started with the `THIS_IS_A_CRON` environment variable

If all you're after is a window where you can see the output of the script while it's running, it's really nothing too different from having:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script 2>&1 >> /random/output/file.txt
```

And opening a terminal that `tail`s the file:

```
tail -100f /random/output/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this show me the actual script output? In the same way as if I had run the php script directly from the shell?

Comment: The `tail` will, because both the `stdout` and `stderr` are set to append to a random file, which will output to your screen via `tail`

Comment: @user2029890: forgive me for saying this, but if it means that much to you to see the actual output of the script, then why bother using `crontab` in the first place? Why not run the script manually? The whole point of crons is to have simple tasks being done for you in the background, without having to monitor the output too much (only if something goes wrong, which is where logs come in)

Comment: @Elisas Fair question. I'm using cron  to schedule when these events run so I do not have to do so manually. The nature of these scripts can be unreliable because they rely on outside events which I cannot fully control. It is therefore useful sometimes to see the output in real-time as I can tell if something is up.

Comment: @user2029890: You could write your scripts in such a way that they are _prone_ to crash (external event, cron should exit: have it crash). log what happened to some log, and set crontab to run the scripts more often. That takes away the strain of you having to constantly monitor the scripts. Have a cleanup script running once every so often, that checks the logs (see if error log has grown too large, or the stdout log isn't growing), and have that script mail/notify you in case of serious trouble

Comment: Good and sane advice.

Comment: An other approach would be to use something like RabbitMQ (AMQP) to respond to the events, so you _can_ have your scripts deal with outside events properly. I can think of a number of additional approaches (not using PHP, in favour of a more responsive tool like node.js, for example)... but that's entirely up to you

Answer (score 0):

If the script is generating output, that you would like to monitor, let it log this and use tail -f on the log.

Using screen for this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible to grep output of /var/log/cron to see old crons, and also new running crons. This is the command used to search for “script.sh” in the cron log file:

```
grep “script.sh” /var/log/cron
```

For checking current running crontabs, it is the best solution as suggested above (using custom log for output), like this:

```
* * * * * /root/script.sh > /tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

then using tail to check for changes when cron is running:

```
tail -f /tmp/script.log
```